# Conditional compilation, how to determine whether a variable has been declared?

Tags: programming, c++, variables

Whilst using #if/#end constructs, how can I determine whether a specific variable has already been declared?,
e.g.,

```
#if [the variable "pinname" has been declared]
Serial.print(F("Pin name: "));
Serial.println(pinname);
#end
```

If this question has been addressed, I cannot find a reference for it.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you use the "#ifdef" directive.

The opposite is "#ifndef".

For example, if you only wanted to include variable definitions once many use this pattern for a header file named, say, "my_variables.h":

```
#ifndef MY_VARIABLES_H
#def MY_VARIABLES_H

int counter;
bool flag;

#endif
```

In this way, no matter how many times you include this file, you only define the variables once.  Because after the 1st time the compiler sees this file, the variable MY_VARIABLES_H is defined and the subsequent time the compiler sees this file, the compiler will skip over the variable defines.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. Simple as that.

I suspect this is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you edit your post stating what you're actually trying to do, I'll edit my answer (or delete it if I don't know).

Comment: my example is exactly what I am trying to do.
@Mark Smith, In this case, specific variables and names are defined based on board attributes.  Another routine is attempting to display such, but obviously only for defined variables.  Of course, I can handle this with the necessary book-keeping.  However, I'd like to know if there is a simpler solution.  If not, I know exactly how to get the results i want.